# Forcing bit length of binary string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, binary

If Im converting an integer like 1 or 8 or 3 to it's binary equivalent using something like:

```
var binary = parseInt(value, 10).toString(2);
```

Is there a way to force the returned value to print out the amount of zeros I want to increase the bit length?

For instance if I want to print 6 as 000110 or 0110 instead of 110?

Comment: little confusing question... parseInt(value, 10).toString(2); won't convert to binary...

Comment: @C-linkNepal If I am converting 6 to binary. How do I return the value of `000110` instead of what is returned as default? Default return is `110`.

Answer (score 1):

write a pad function

something like

```
function pad(s, size) {    
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}
```

and use like

```
var binary = parseInt(value, 10).toString(2); //binary is "110", if value is 6
var paddedBinary = pad(binary,6); //paddedBinary is "000110"
```